# Using i++ as a class name php

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

I'm trying to add class names like

> folder1,folder2,folder3

at the beginning of the `$row_me_blue` variable by using a

> tbody id

Currently I get `<div id="null">`

When I dump the `$i` I get `int(1),int(31),int(61) and int(91)` while I'm trying to return `1,2,3 and 4` to add to the div id. Any ideas on why this is occuring? Is this a scope issue?

I've also tried `strval($i)` just to see if I can use the string that comes from that, but still receive the null value on the front end.

```
<?php
$i=0;
$wrap_count = 30; // number of divs to wrap  in tbody
foreach ($rows as $row ){
    $product_num = stripslashes ($row->product_num);
    $product_name = stripslashes ($row->product_name);
    $i+=1;
    if($i%$wrap_count==1)
    {

        $row_me_blue .= "<tbody id='folder$i'>";
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($i);
        echo "</pre><br>";  
    }   
    $row_me_blue = "<tr>";
    $row_me_blue .= "<td>$product_num</td>";
    $row_me_blue .= "<td><b>$product_name</b></td>";
    $row_me_blue .= "</tr>";
    if($i%$wrap_count==0)
    {
        $row_me_blue .= '</tbody>';
    }
    echo $row_me_blue;
}
if($i%$wrap_count!=0)
{
    $row_me_blue .= '</tbody>';
}
echo "</table>";//end row_me_blue
?>
```

Comment: You're var_dump()ing inside a block that happens when $i mod 30 == 1, i.e. when $i is 1, 31, 61, 91, etc :) hence, it var_dump()s int(1), int(31), int(61), int(91), etc!

Comment: I see what you mean. Is there any way to grab the count of those to include in the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Operator `$i%$wrap_count` give you sequence 1,2,3,4,5,..29, 0, 1.. Condition  `==1`  is true when $1 = 1, 31, 61. Nothing is wrong.

Remove if and just use

```
$row_me_blue .= "<tbody id='folder". $i%$wrap_count."'>";
```

Comment: It seems that this no longer wraps every `$wrap_count` quantity. It now wraps each one.

Comment: I'm sorry splash, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: $i = 0; $w = 15; while ($i < 50) { echo $i$w.'<br>'; $i++; } see output

Comment: Write on phone, loos $i%$w )